# Get path of tilde in python

Tags: python

How would I do the following:

```
f=open('~/.bash_profile')
```

Is there a way to resolve the `~` path without using something like subprocess?

Comment: Did you try it?  On what OS?

Comment: @vaultah thank you for the redirect, that was exactly what I was looking for.